# how could i flash a message to users before a deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Using capistrano for deploys, is it possible to flash a message to users that are on when a deploy has started, or before so that they know the site will be slow and unresponsive for a few minutes?

Comment: It might be a better practice to switch your app into maintenance mode during deployments, especially if they're short and you do them in off-peak hours. You don't want people interacting with your database while you're doing migrations, in particular.

Comment: Thanks, i think i'll do that combined with the answer i got to flash a warning about going into maintenance mode in X amount of time so if there are people on they can know i'll be down for a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Capistrano hooks to execute a Rails runner, which could hook into your application and globally display a message.

You will need to code the global message logic into your application, and then accesses it via `rails runner` command at appropriate hook points within Capistrano.